# power 12v solenoid from DC jack of Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage, voltage-protection

I was wondering if it is possible to power up a 12V solenoid valve from the DC jack of the Arduino Uno, provided that I'm powering the Arduino from the same jack:
[image]

Comment: the Arduino is kind of irrelevant to the question ... make a Y cable instead of soldering to the connector ... cut the existing cable and splice a pigtail into it

Comment: i would use a dc jack Y adapter instead of splicing the wire, but whatever's clever should suffice.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments, I was just afraid of frying my setup 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's the same as if you were directly soldering a second plug to your power supply. Just make sure the power supply delivers enough current for your solenoid (the power used by the Arduino will be comparably negligible).